# how to reduce the gap between this widgets? I tried tweaking padding values but no luck so far. Please take a look

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

This is the code
I tweaked the paading but no luck. I am new to flutter manage to build this but stuck, any suggestions/help is much appreciated!

```
import 'package:bmi_app_one/utils/TextStyle_Decorations.dart';
import 'package:bmi_app_one/utils/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class home_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _home_screenState createState() => _home_screenState();
}

class _home_screenState extends State<home_screen> {

  Color _appBar_bg_color = HexColor('#1C1C1E');
  Color _app_bg_color = HexColor('#2c2c2e');
  bool changeButtonColorMale = false;
  bool changeButtonColorFemale = false;
  int age = 20;
  int weight = 30;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: homeScreenAppBarText,
        backgroundColor: _appBar_bg_color,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      backgroundColor: _app_bg_color,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
              height: 0.6.sh,
              child: Row(
                /* Entry Point of 1st set */
                children: [
                  /* This contains both Male and female gender button */
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          /* Male Button */
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 4, 8),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                debugPrint("Gender: Male pressed");
                                setState(() {
                                  if(changeButtonColorMale == false){
                                    changeButtonColorMale = true;
                                    changeButtonColorFemale = false;
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    changeButtonColorMale = false;
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 0.4.sw,
                                height: 0.2.sh,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                      child: Icon(Ionicons.ios_male,size: 88.ssp,
                                          color: changeButtonColorMale ? Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.7) : Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Male", style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.ssp,
                                        fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                        color: changeButtonColorMale ? Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.7) : Colors.white
                                    ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                            ),
                          ),
                          /* Age */
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 8),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 0.43.sw,
                              height: 0.2.sh,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  /* Age Text */
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 36, 8, 8),
                                    child: Text("AGE",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.ssp,
                                      fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                      color: Colors.white
                                    ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      /* Age decrease icon */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                        child: IconButton(
                                          icon: new Icon(
                                            MaterialCommunityIcons.minus_circle_outline,
                                            size: 42.ssp,
                                            color: Colors.white,),
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            debugPrint("Age decreased by 1");
                                            setState(() {
                                              if(age <= 5){

                                              }
                                              else{
                                                age --;
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                          splashRadius: 0.1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      /* Display Age in numbers */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8 , 0, 0),
                                        child: Text(age.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 26.ssp,
                                          fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                        ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      /* Age increase icon */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 0, 0),
                                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon: new Icon(
                                              MaterialCommunityIcons.plus_circle_outline,
                                            size: 42.ssp,
                                            color: Colors.white,),
                                          onPressed: (){
                                              debugPrint("Age increased by 1");
                                              setState(() {
                                                if(age >= 90){

                                                }
                                                else{
                                                  age ++;
                                                }
                                              });
                                          },
                                          splashRadius: 0.1,
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          /* Female Button */
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 4, 0),
                            child: new InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                debugPrint("Gender: Female pressed");
                                setState(() {
                                  if(changeButtonColorFemale == false){
                                    changeButtonColorFemale = true;
                                    changeButtonColorMale = false;
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    changeButtonColorFemale = false;
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 0.4.sw,
                                height: 0.2.sh,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                      child: Icon(Ionicons.ios_female,size: 88.ssp,
                                          color: changeButtonColorFemale ? Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.7) : Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Female", style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 24.ssp,
                                        fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                        color: changeButtonColorFemale ? Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.7) : Colors.white
                                    ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),


                            ),
                          ),

                          /* Weight */
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 8),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 0.43.sw,
                              height: 0.2.sh,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  /* Weight Text */
                                  Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 36, 3, 8),
                                        child: Text("WEIGHT",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 24.ssp,
                                              fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                              color: Colors.white
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text("(Kg)",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                                          fontSize: 11.ssp,
                                          fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      /* Weight decrease icon */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                        child: IconButton(
                                          icon: new Icon(
                                            MaterialCommunityIcons.minus_circle_outline,
                                            size: 42.ssp,
                                            color: Colors.white,),
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            debugPrint("Weight decreased by 1");
                                            setState(() {
                                              if(weight <= 5){

                                              }
                                              else{
                                                weight --;
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                          splashRadius: 0.1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      /* Display Weight in numbers */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8 , 0, 0),
                                        child: Text(weight.toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 26.ssp,
                                            fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      /* Weight increase icon */
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 0, 0),
                                        child: IconButton(
                                          icon: new Icon(
                                            MaterialCommunityIcons.plus_circle_outline,
                                            size: 42.ssp,
                                            color: Colors.white,),
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            debugPrint("Weight increased by 1");
                                            setState(() {
                                              if(weight >= 625){

                                              }
                                              else{
                                                weight ++;
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                          splashRadius: 0.1,
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            /* Height Slider 2nd set */
            Container(
              width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
              height: 0.15.sh,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the screenshot at present
[image: App screenshot]

tweaked the paading but no luck. I am new to flutter manage to build this but stuck, any suggestions/help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you try changing mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating that extra space with how you're setting the height of the 2nd `Container` at the top of your build method. I assume that the `sh` in `height: 0.6.sh,` is ScreenHeight * 0.6?

It doesn't appear that either of those first 2 `Container`'s are adding anything of value.  You can just remove them both and your white `Container` at the bottom should jump up closer to everything else.

Comment: tweaked the first container height from 0.6.sh to 0.5.sh. It is working as expected now.